# Any plugin to send notifications to users when an article is published?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, subscriptions

I need a plugin for Joomla 3 to send an email to some users when a new article is published or a new document is added to Docman. I've been looking at the Joomla Extensions Directory, but I haven't found any plugin for this function.

Do you know any plugin that works this way?

Comment: Have you tried to install http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-submission/18594 ?

Comment: @zkanoca: I'm not sure if this plugin does what I need. Anyway, I want a free plugin (I work on a huge business and buying Joomla components is a PITA...)

Comment: *Huge business* and not wanting to buy a [$9.99 extension](http://www.orware.com/view/subscribe), that doesn't really sound logical to me.
`I have to tell you, besides docman populate this is the best plugin for Docman. My main gripe with docman and other download components is that when you have more than 5 files, no one wants to scroll through 5 pages to view them. -DOCman forum user`

Comment: @johanpw: I lost a month on burocracy just to buy Docman ($59 subscription), and I don't want to lose another month to buy this $9.99 plugin... This is the reason why I want a free plugin. From the business there isn't any problems (except filling some papers and get approval from 3 o 4 different departments), but it's easier for me to write a plugin from scratch... :(

Comment: If you're unable to find the extension you need and are not able to pay for an extension, then the only thing you can do is write a small plugin. Not sure if you can see @GDP's answer as he deleted it, but this is a good way to start. Have a read of the Joomla documentation for additional info

Answer (score 1):

Earlier version of Docman included a plugin called Docman Notify, but according to the developers website,

> 2. Notify plugin doesn't work in 2.0. We are working on a new Notify plugin. This is in the works.

<sup>Source: [Joomlatools forum](http://www.joomlatools.com/support/forums/topic/3752-file-permissions-and-notify?highlight=notify)</sup>

Although you don't want to use commercial extensions, [Content Update Notifications](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-submission/18594) seems to be your best option.

Another (free) alternative is [NotifyArticleSubmit](http://gruz.org.ua/en/extensions/notifyarticlesubmit-get-email-notification-when-an-article-is-added-or-changed.html). I haven't used it myself, and I don't now if it works with Docman, but if it doesn't you might be able to modify it to fit your needs.

As others pointed out, you could also build your own plugin, using any of the existing events as needed:

- **onContentBeforeDelete** : This is an event that is called right before the content is deleted.
- **onContentAfterDelete** : This is an event that is called right after the content is deleted.
- **onContentBeforeDisplay** : This is a request for information that should be placed immediately before the generated content.
- **onContentAfterDisplay**: This is a request for information that should be placed immediately after the generated content.
- **onContentBeforeSave** : This is an event that is called right before the content is saved into the database.
- **onContentAfterSave** : This is an event that is called after the content is saved into the database.
- **onContentAfterTitle** : This is a request for information that should be placed between the content title and the content body.
- **onContentChangeState** : This is an event that is called when the contents state is changed.
- **onContentPrepare** : This is the first stage in preparing content for output and is the most common point for content orientated plugins to do their work.

More info on plugin development can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_content_plugin).

Answer (score 1):

DOCman Notify 2.0 is now available which offers support for DOCman 2.x.

DOCman Notify is a plugin that sends notification emails to document and category owners about changes in those documents and categories that they manage.

- Document owners will get an email notification whenever the documents they own are edited or deleted.
- Category owners will get notification emails whenever a document is added to, deleted from or edited in the categories they own.

> Tip: To make a registered user a document or category owner select the user in the ‘owner’ select box in the category or document form.

For more information see [the release announcement on our blog](http://www.joomlatools.com/blog/2014/12/email-notifications-download-limiting-and-license-support-for-docman-are-here.html).